# Regular expressions inside Angular Validators

Tags: regex, angular

The following two regular expressions are valid ones:

```
Email validation
[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$…-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?

 UK Post code validation
^([Bb][Ff][Pp][Oo] ?[0-9]{1,3})$|^(([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0…hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]) ?)))[0-9][A-Za-z]{2} ?))$
```

However, when putting them into Angular Reactive forms:

```
address: this.fb.group({
                 previousPostCode: ["",
                [
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.minLength(5),
                    Validators.maxLength(8),
                    Validators.pattern(/^([Bb][Ff][Pp][Oo] ?[0-9]{1,3})$|^(([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0…hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]) ?)))[0-9][A-Za-z]{2} ?))$/)
                ]
            ],
})
```

I am getting the following error: `Error parsing regular expression: Invalid regular expression: /^([Bb][Ff][Pp][Oo] ?[0-9]{1,3})$|^(([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0…hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]) ?)))[0-9][A-Za-z]{2} ?))$/: Unmatched ')'` . I am using VS 2017. Any idea? **I am mainly interested in the post code validation.**

Comment: That's because you have 4 `)` more than you should. What are you trying to match? Might be easier to actually rewrite a regex pattern. You have another potential mistake in your pattern, a missing `[` before `0…`

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that [Validators.email](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#email) was added in v4

Comment: Error in the email regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+ 
     (?: \. [a-zA-Z0-9!#$…-9] )?
     \.
=    )  <-- Unbalanced  ')'
     + [a-zA-Z0-9]
     (?: [a-zA-Z0-9-]* [a-zA-Z0-9] )?
`

Comment: Error in postal code regex: `^
     ( [Bb] [Ff] [Pp] [Oo] [ ]? [0-9]{1,3} )  # (1)
     $ 
  |  ^
     (                             # (2 start)
          ( [Gg] [Ii] [Rr] [ ]0…hJ-Yj-y] [0-9]? [A-Za-z] )  # (3)
          [ ]?
     )                             # (2 end)
=    )  <-- Unbalanced  ')'
=    )  <-- Unbalanced  ')'
     [0-9] [A-Za-z]{2} [ ]?
=    )  <-- Unbalanced  ')'
=    )  <-- Unbalanced  ')'
     $`